# Disable Validator but Validator Callout still shows and causes validation

Tags: asp.net, javascript, validation

I'm trying to validate that a certain increment of a product was entered in the product qty textbox that is in a repeater.  The problem is that the increment is different for every product, so I need that as a variable for each call to validate it (which I don't think you can do with a custom validator), and I need it client side with a ValidatorCalloutExtender.  The best solution i have come up with is to trigger a RegEx validator that will evaluate false via my own javascript (another validator takes care of making sure its a valid number).  The problem is that with the ValidatorCalloutExtender, when I disable the validator it still marks it as invalid (the textbox flashes white then turns yellow again (meaning its invalid), even though I placed JavaScript alerts and I know the validator is getting disabled.  Anyone have any ideas as to whats going on here?  Here is the code.  Thanks!

PS: Everything works fine w/out the validatorCalloutExtender, but I really need the Callout Extender!

The validators:

```
<asp:RegularExpressionValidator ID="ProductIncrementValidator" runat="server"
  ControlToValidate="ProductQtyTxt"
  ErrorMessage="Please enter a valid increment"
  ValidationExpression="^triggerthisvalidation$"
  Enabled="false"
  Display="Dynamic"
  SetFocusOnError="true"
  ValidationGroup="productValidation">
</asp:RegularExpressionValidator>

<ajax:ValidatorCalloutExtender ID="ProductIncrementVE" runat="server"
  TargetControlID="ProductIncrementValidator"
  HighlightCssClass="validator"
  WarningIconImageUrl="~/img/blank.gif">
</ajax:ValidatorCalloutExtender>
```

When Databinding the product:

```
Dim productQtyTxt As TextBox
productQtyTxt = CType(e.Item.FindControl("ProductQtyTxt"), TextBox)

Dim incrementValidator As RegularExpressionValidator
incrementValidator = CType(e.Item.FindControl("ProductIncrementValidator"), RegularExpressionValidator)
incrementValidator.ErrorMessage = "Please enter an increment of " & product.OrderIncrement.ToString()


' Add item qty increment check
productQtyTxt.Attributes.Add("onChange", "javascript:checkIncrement('" _
  & productQtyTxt.ClientID & "', " _
  & product.OrderIncrement & ", '" _
  & incrementValidator.ClientID & "')")
```

The Javascript:

```
    function checkIncrement(textboxID, incrementQty, validatorID) {
    var textbox = $get(textboxID);
    var incrementValidator = $get(validatorID);
    var qtyEntered = textbox.value;

    if ((qtyEntered % incrementQty) != 0) {
        ValidatorEnable(incrementValidator, true);
        alert("not valid");
        return;
    }
    else {
        ValidatorEnable(incrementValidator, false);
        alert("valid");
        return;
    }
}
```

Comment: I set the textbox's cssclass to blank in the javascript function and hid the callout, so now that works but when focus is set on the box it calls the validation and tries to validate against my ^triggerthisvalidation$ expression for the RegEx validator.  How can I make it not trigger validation on focus?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I had the same problem, i solved with something like this

```
if ((qtyEntered % incrementQty) != 0) {
    ValidatorEnable(incrementValidator, true);
    $("#" + validatorID + "_ValidatorCalloutExtender_popupTable").show();
    alert("not valid");
    return;
}
else {
    ValidatorEnable(incrementValidator, false);
    $("#" + validatorID + "_ValidatorCalloutExtender_popupTable").hide();
    alert("valid");
    return;
}
```

Hope this helps someone.

Answer (score 1):

1.Set CSS class for ValidatorCalloutExtender:

```
<style id = "style1" type="text/css">
        .CustomValidator
        {
            position: relative;
            margin-left: -80px;
            margin-top: 8px;
            display: inherit;
        }
</style>
```

```
<ajax:ValidatorCalloutExtender ID="ProductIncrementVE" runat="server"
  TargetControlID="ProductIncrementValidator"
  HighlightCssClass="validator"
  WarningIconImageUrl="~/img/blank.gif" 
  CssClass="CustomValidator">
</ajax:ValidatorCalloutExtender>
```

2 . Use JavaScript to alter this CSS class when needed. Set display = none:

```
function alterDisplay(type) {
    var styleSheet, cssRule;
    if (document.styleSheets) {
        styleSheet = document.styleSheets[index1];
        if (styleSheet) {
            if (styleSheet.cssRules)
                cssRule = styleSheet.cssRules[index2]; // Firefox
            else if (styleSheet.rules)
                cssRule = styleSheet.rules[index2];         // IE
            if (cssRule) {
                cssRule.style.display = type;
            }

        }
    }
}
```

**Note:** the index1 and index2 may be difference from pages, it's up to your declaration. You can use IE debugger to find our the correctly indexs.